# Como listar várias colunas usando o Inner Join e o left join?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Como posso fazer para pegar dados de duas tabelas?

Exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: insira o código aqui]

os campos

```
`assunto,nomeremetente,cpfremetente,observacao` da tabela **protocolos**
```

e o `datacriacao` da tabela **protocolo_documentos**

é do protocolo_documentos é `dataformat(datacriacao,'%d/%m/%Y') as datacriacao` ficando assim a query de inicial .

```
$Query ="SELECT 
                        dataformat(datacriacao,'%d/%m/%Y') as datacriacao,
                         assunto,nomeremetente,cpfremetente,observacao 
                           FROM protocolos 
                               ORDER BY formatted_date DESC";
```

Comment: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Comment: @rray Você tá muito rápido hoje :p

Comment: @rray quer pegar somente a datacriacao da tabela  protocolo_documentos e o restante da tabela protocolos.

Comment: @allanaraujo, qual relação entre as tabelas?

Comment: Quero pegar todos os dados  assunto,nomeremetente,cpfremetente,observacao  e trazer conforma o datacriacao  de protocolo_documentos

Answer (score 0):

Você precisar especificar a relação entre as duas tabelas na clausula `ON`, conforme o exemplo abaixo

```
SELECT dataformat(pd.datacriacao,'%d/%m/%Y') as datacriacao, p.*
FROM protocolos p
join protocolo_Documentos pd
on pd.protocolo = p.protocolo -- aqui tem que ser a relação entre as duas tabelas
ORDER BY formatted_date DESC
```

Quanto ao uso do JOIN ou LEFT JOIN, veja como usar [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448).